# Python code making excel file corrupt. How to correct this?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am writing a code for copying cells from a large excel file(11740 rows) to another large excel file (78472 rows). Both the files have 31 columns. When I run the below code it throws error, sometimes memory error or sometimes permission denied error. After that it corrupts the file, and when I manually open the file, I get the following error msg,

> 'We found a problem with some content in 'File1.xlsx'. Do you want us
>   to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook,click Yes.'

Even if I click Yes, I don't see anything in my workbook.

Here is the code

```
import openpyxl
import os
os.chdir('C:\\PYP')
wb1=openpyxl.load_workbook('File1.xlsx')
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('File2.xlsx')
tgt=wb1.get_sheet_by_name('Trove GL Report')
src=wb2.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
lim1=tgt.max_row
lim2=src.max_row
clim=31
lim3=lim1+lim2
lim3
for i in range(1,lim2+1,1):
    for j in range(1,clim+1,1):
        tgt.cell(row=lim1+i,column=j).value=src.cell(row=i+1,column=j).value
wb1.save('File1.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is really big then you should read it in chunks to avoid memory errors.

**Snippet:**

```
import pandas as pd

excel = pd.ExcelFile("File1.xlsx")

for sheet in excel.sheet_names:
  reader = excel.parse(sheet, chunksize=1000):
  for chunk in reader:
      #parse chunk here
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special `read_only` mode in Openpyxl to allow reading large workbooks with reduced memory overhead. Full information can be found in the documentation at http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html.

The change in your code would simply be:

```
wb2=openpyxl.load_workbook('File2.xlsx', read_only=True)
```

This won't help with memory usage for the workbook you're writing, but may be enough to avoid the memory errors you're seeing. If not, it could be worth reading data from the target file, writing it to a new workbook first using `write-only` mode before appending the new data (caveat: I haven't tried this, so not sure it will bring any benefit).

If I understand correctly from your code that you're trying to append the data from one workbook to another, the code can probably be simplified somewhat also - e.g.:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
tgt_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('File1.xlsx')
src_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook('File2.xlsx', read_only=True)
tgt_ws=tgt_wb['Trove GL Report']
src_ws=src_wb['Sheet2']
for row, row_cells in enumerate(src_ws.rows, tgt_ws.max_row + 1):
    for col, cell in enumerate(row_cells, 1):
      tgt_ws.cell(row=row, column=col).value = cell.value
tgt_wb.save('File1.xlsx')
```